# Create A Block To Add Field Collection Item

Tags: entities

I want to create a block that would hold links to add different field collection items. How would i do this? I am new to drupal, please point me to right direction or help me get started.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module yet? You can easily create blocks and add whatever field items you want through it. It's a very powerful and at times complex module so you can refer to the [nodeOne](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone) video tutorials. Good luck!

Comment: I tried views but it didn't accomplish what i wanted and views consumes alot of memory and i don't want that for the site i'm building. What i want is take the add link from below the node and create a block that resides in the sidebar for users to add field collection items."an example would be hubpages"